# Who vs that correct use

Tags: relative-pronouns

**That** is used as a restrictive form and can be used with people, animals and things.
**Who** is mostly used with people.

I am confused where to use these two in the following particular situation:

Examples

1. The child that came here yesterday is dead.
2. The boys who were watching the match clapped heartily.

What is difference between these two sentences?

Comment: In spoken English *that* is often used with people; in written English one finds *who* more often, except in written dialogs. You can use (say) either 'that'  or 'who'  in both sentences; I'd recommend writing both with 'who'.

Comment: See the *Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English* (Biber et al 1999), p.612, for what is perhaps a more accurate account of the distribution of *who* and *that* in different registers.